# Numpy structured array document confusion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a total newbie to numpy structured arrays.

If I use the code from the docs (see here:  [Numpy Structured Array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html))

```
import numpy as np 
x=np.array([(1,2.,'Hello'), (2,3.,"World")], dtype=[('foo', 'i4'),('bar', 'f4'), ('baz', 'S10')])
x
y = x['foo']
y
```

`x` is correct: `array([(1, 2.0, 'Hello'), (2, 3.0, 'World')], dtype=[('foo', '<i4'), ('bar', '<f4'), ('baz', 'S10')])`

However `y` gives me `array([1, 2])` and the docs say it should be `array([ 2.,  3.], dtype=float32)`

I have a hard time believing the docs are wrong but this code is so short and and I copied/pasted it into python.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like a documentation error to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x['foo']` gives you an array of all first elements of each structure, so `[1,2]` is correct. The documentation mistakenly switched `foo` and `bar`, so read the docs as

```
y = x['bar']
```

and the rest of the example is correct.

Comment: Kinda crazy a noob can find this...  How does someone go about correcting the docs?

Comment: @user918967 You should open a new issue on the [numpy GitHub page](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues)

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/index.html warns that the 'user guide' is a work in progress.  Evidently developers have put more effort in to the `reference` section, as well as responding to code errors.